Compare two strings easily with Unicode support
to understand C++, I'm trying to program a comparator between two character strings.
The first variable can be a constant because it is the one being compared. In my case it necessarily contains Unicode characters.
The second variable is an input, which must be exact to the 1st variable.
My code reports "name", doesn't matter. Since I spent more than 2 hours there, my code is probably far from the result I hope:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        string name;
        cout << "Can you please give me your name ? : ";
        getline(std::cin, name);

        string expectedName = "äëö";

        if (name == expectedName) {
            cout << "You are a truly GOAT" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            throw (name);
        }
    }
    catch (string name) {
        cout << "Name is: " << typeid(name).name();
    }

    cin.ignore(); //VStudio
    return 0;
}

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022, and I didn't use the ICU library as IAs told me because I don't understand it.
I ask you to keep it simple and short, especially if only one variable is needed (for example).
